# jQuery.ajax new element check

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, refresh, element

im trying to make loging to web page using ajax. I have this:

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/login.php",
       data: dataString,               
       success: function(answer) {
           $('#loging').html(answer);           
       }      
    });
```

It works fine, BUT: In answer variable is something like this:

```
    Hi user, <span id="logout_button">Logout</span>
```

I can see button "Logout", but my browser dont know here is any span id="logout_button". I have code for logout binded with #logout_button but it dosnt work, because my browser knows nothing about this button. When I refresh page, logout works fine.

So, is there any way/function how to say to jQuery "hi buddy, please check for the new elements on document"?

Comment: please define "works fine" and "doesnot work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use .delegate() instead of .bind()

```
$('body').delegate('#logout_button', 'click', function() {
    //here the code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For jquery 1.7+ it's better to use "on"

```
$("body").on("click", "#logout_button", function() {
    //here the code
});
```